# is there any way to have icon for .exe file that created as an entry point using pypi?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I made python package for a gui application(pyqt5 base) there is a problem when I search for it using  windows search  the app doesn't have any icon is there any way to fix it ? I'm looking for a way through setup.py (config file for making python package)

[image]

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="subtodl", 
    packages = ['Scripts'], 
    version="0.0.1",
    license='MIT',     
    description = 'a handy tools to download subtitle ',   
    author = 'mehdi',                  
    install_requires=[
    "pyqt5; platform_system=='Windows'", 
    "beautifulsoup4", 
    "lxml",
    "PyQt5==5.11.3 ;platform_system=='Linux'",
    "requests",
    "wget",
    ],
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6",
    ],
    entry_points={

        'gui_scripts': [
        'subtodl= Scripts.subtodlmain:main',
    ],
    },
)
```

Comment: The package doesn't have an icon because 'the package' isn't any specific file. You presumably want an icon *for the .exe created as an entry point*. Also, none of this has anything to do with PyPI; Python packages are just "packages" and PyPI is just a *place that people can share them*.

Comment: I think you got it wrong yeah i know what is a package and how it works and as u already mention i want a icon for  exe that created as an entry point  i know it possible (for example after installing qt designer package the exe file have icon) but I don't know how to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i finally found the answer but it seems that is an old way to do so and i don't know how to make it cross platform also don't know how to not hard code path
but it does work i just test it on a Linux base machine

```
    data_files=[
    ('/share/applications', [subtodl.desktop"])
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do what you want is:

1. Create a shortcut to the app (drag it somewhere while holding ctrl and shift).
2. Right click the shortcut and click properties.
3. Click change icon, and select the icon file you want.

Now to open your app you just need to double click your shortcut that can be placed anywhere.